# WPFToolkit Datagrid not showing column splitter

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I am using the WPF Datagrid. I have set the resize property of columns in datagrid to true. Still it doesn't show splitter icon on columns of datagrid.

WpfToolkit version is 3.5.31016.1

Comment: 1. what's your header style? .NET version?, are you responding on Cell or something similra .._SizeChanged events?

Comment: I have no header style set. I am using .NET 4 and have no events connected to to the grid.

Comment: that's weird, should just work out of the box, do you have some other global styles that Target certain controls like TextBlocks etc.. also post your code

Comment: I'm expanding a third party program to include new features which include showing data in a datagrid. This program does set some styles but not to target type columnHeader. I cannot post my code since I don't know what part of the entire program is causing this issue. Thanks.

Comment: create a specific style for a column header - override the template, that might help. Snoop, ColumnHeader I think it's a button under the template, so if the 3rd party forces styles without specifying target names, these styles might mess with your header column.